# R print() in pipe coerces wrong type

Tags: r, pipe

when print() is used in a pipe it seems to be coercing x to the type of .

```
seq(1,10,1) %T>% print(x=summary(.)) %>% summary()
```

gives

```
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1       3       6       6       8      10 
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
1.00    3.25    5.50    5.50    7.75   10.00
```

What I initially wanted was to get sd() in addition to summary() and tried:

```
seq(1,10,1) %T>% print(x=sd(.)) %>% summary()
```

but got:

```
[1] 3
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   1.00    3.25    5.50    5.50    7.75   10.00 
>
```

I tried variations with cat() and c() but the digits 1:10 go into the 1st dot of those functions.

The general question would be is there a way to use pipe operators to display multiple summaries or functions of what is moving through the pipe. I know I could have used one pipe ending in sd() and a 2nd pipe ending in summary() - but the beginning of my pipe is much more complicated than seq(1,10,1) and I wanted to avoid repeating or saving into an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap it inside parentheses

```
library(magrittr)
seq(1,10,1) %T>% 
        {print(x=summary(.))} %>%
         summary
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   1.00    3.25    5.50    5.50    7.75   10.00 
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   1.00    3.25    5.50    5.50    7.75   10.00
```

Or with the second case

```
seq(1,10,1) %T>% {print(x=sd(.))} %>% summary()
[1] 3.02765
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   1.00    3.25    5.50    5.50    7.75   10.00
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. Pushing deeper, why does making it a block with {} avoid the issue? How does it change the behavior of left or right hand side in the pipe?

Comment: @D.Bontempo it is related to the order of evaluation in pipe.  Here, you are trying to apply multiple statements i.e. `x = summary(.)` then `print` etc, which are multiple expressions wrapped together, thus blocking it with {} would help